# Can we get rid of bean definition for Aspects using Spring-AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop, aop

My Aspect is as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect{
    //define pointcuts
    // define Advices pertaining to pointcuts
}
```

My aspect-config xml file:

```
<?xml ...?>
  <beans ...
   xmlns:aop
   xmlns:context ..>
      <bean id="someAspect" class="...SomeAspect"/>
      <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

  </beans>
```

This runs perfectly fine

**What I require:**

I want to get rid of writing bean definition for each Aspect as shown above in my config xml file.

**I tried the following:**

Added `@Component` on `SomeAspect` and in xml added `<context-component-scan>` with respective package containing my Aspect hoping that my class gets picked up as a Bean and as an Aspect.
However, my Aspect was not getting picked up at all.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `context:component-scan` element has a sub-element which you can use to include annotation classes to use to be picked up by the scan.

Take a look at the `context:include-filter` element, and its attributes.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.to.scan">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

I would think what you tried would have work, but without seeing it exactly as you did it, it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Perfect! it works only if the include-filter...which is kind of surprising because it should have picked up by default. Thanks @nicholas.hauschild !